# css3 using two animation : secound animation not starting from first animation postion

Tags: css, css-animations

i'm studying css3 animation from a playlist in youtube , i made a box comes from top and make swing
my problem is that when make a swing not starting where first animation left, here's the code :

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <span>X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    transform: translateY(100px);
    background: red;
    transform-origin: 10px 10px;
    animation: box 2s forwards,mm 1s 3s  linear forwards;
}

span{
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background-color: yellow;
}
@keyframes box {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(-200px);opacity: 0;
    }
    70%{
        transform: translateY(150px);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(100px); opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes mm {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(100px);transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    40%{
        transform: translateY(100px);transform: rotateZ(90deg);
    }
    70%{
        transform: translateY(100px);transform: rotateZ(70deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(100px);transform: rotateZ(75deg);
    }
}
```

wheres the problem ?
here's the video that i watched for this animation: [CSS Animation Tutorial #11 - Animating a Pop-up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0_M1y4aFAQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've done it wrong in 'mm' keyframes,
when you are writing transform, you are doing

```
transform: translateY(100px);
transform: rotateZ(0deg);
```

and this first transform property gets overridden by the second transform property (Cascading), so writing it like this would fix it.

```
@keyframes mm {
   0%{
       transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(0deg);
     }
   40%{
       transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(90deg);
     }
   70%{
       transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(70deg);
     }
   100%{
       transform: translateY(100px) rotateZ(75deg);
     }
}
```

[Checkout the codepen here](https://codepen.io/sumanth-bettadapura/pen/wvBoMOj)

Comment: thnx for help :)